# Most pythonic way to check string contains substring which is also present in list

Tags: python, string, list, python-2.7

I have string ,

```
str='http://facebook.com/something/something/1.php'
```

And have list ,

```
l= ['facebook','twitter']
```

I want to check that the str has atleast any of the keyword from the list. What is the most pythonic way to acheive this?

What I have tried is ,

```
flag=0
for i in l:
    if i in str:
        print 'YES'
        flag=1
        break;

if flag==1:
     #process something
```

Comment: What is the excepted result for `str=http://facebooker.com` or `str='retwitter.com`?

Comment: @georg result for `str=http://facebooker.com or str='retwitter.com ` should be false.

Comment: So you're looking for _words_ and not just substrings? `any` solutions won't work for you then.

Answer (score 4):

Using [`any`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) and [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions):

```
>>> s = 'http://facebook.com/something/something/1.php'
>>> l = ['facebook','twitter']
>>> any(x in s for x in l)
True
```

Side note: Don't use `str` as a variable name. It shadows a builtin funciton/type [`str`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#str).

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#any) and a [generator expression](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators).

```
s = 'http://facebook.com/something/something/1.php'
l= ['facebook','twitter']

if any(i in s for i in l):
    print('YES')
```

`any(i in s for i in l)` will iterate over `l` and test each element to see if it is a substring of `s`. If a substring is found then the iteration will halt and it will return `True`, otherwise it will continue until finished and then return `False`.

The complimentary method of `any` is [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#all) which will only return `True` if all are `True` (i.e. all strings are substrings).

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
url = 'http://facebook.com/something/something/1.php'
patterns = ['facebook','twitter']
print('YES' if any(pattern in url for pattern in patterns) else 'False')
```

Alternative

```
print('YES' if any(url.find(pattern) > -1 for pattern in patterns) else 'False')
```

Comment: You can replace **find** with **index** and it should still work.

Comment: If you use `index`, it will raise a `ValueError` if there no matching substring.

Comment: Alternative has syntax errors. `print('YES' if any(url.find(pattern) > -1 for pattern in patterns) else 'False')`

Comment: @falsetru Pythonic way is to EAFP(Easier to ask for forgiveness than permission) however errors would be thrown most of times so I guess it does not apply in this case.

Comment: Then, it does not make sense to print **False**. You misunderstood the EAFP.

Answer (score 0):

**Embrace the regex in it**

well this is all about [regex](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) for me.  Your time invested learning regular expressions will be well rewarded.

```
import re

str='http://facebook.com/something/something/1.php'
l = ['facebook','twitter']

# create the regex
re_l = '|'.join(l)

if re.search(re_l, str):
    print "yes"
    # do something
```

This will be faster than any of the other alternatives and allows you to fine tune things.  e.g.

```
# precompile the regex so it only gets done once
re_l = re.compile('|'.join(ll))
# not faster for one but if you reuse it this is faster.
if re_l.search(str):
    print "doing something"
```

BTW since you are looking at the domain name in this example, you can add the re.IGNORECASE flag easily `re.compile('|'.join(ll), re.I)`